# Passing ID into a static route -- match page.url => "pages#show", :id => page.id -- not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm trying to create page model with activeadmin, and awesome_nested_set. I've been trying to figure out how to create dynamic routes with the correct trailing slugs (e.g. /page1/page1subpage/a-subpage-of-page1subpage/ etc). I found a post by someone else here with some rails2 code I turned into this inside my routes.rb:

```
Page.all.each do |page|
  page.url = "/"+page.self_and_ancestors.map{|p| p.slug}.join("/")
  page.save
  match page.url => "pages#show", :id => page.id
end
```

It's just not passing any IDs through. How do I get rails3 to pass the ID into the route?? it's just connecting all the pages to pages#show with no id param.

Also if there's a better way to do this in rails 3 let me know.

EDIT: it looks like rails doesn't like passing :id as a param.. If I change it to :page_id it works..

```
match page.url, :controller => 'pages', :action => 'show', :page_id => page.id
```

How can I reload the routes or do this within active record though?

Answer (later edit): I ended up making a after_validation method that checks if slug_changed? and for itself and it's ancestors and descendants, re creates a url for itself, saves it, then calls:

```
MyAppName::Application.reload_routes!
```

And I removed the page.save method in the routes.. that also causes some problems when doing things like rake db:migrate on new DBs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`match` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Base.html#method-i-match) should recognize the `:id`:

> Any options not seen here are passed on as params with the url.

I don't know why `:id` and `:page_id` are being treated differently. You could use [`:defaults`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#defining-defaults) to set default values in `params` though:

> You can also define other defaults in a route by supplying a hash for the `:defaults` option. This even applies to parameters that you do not specify as dynamic segments.

So try this:

```
Page.all.each do |page|
  page.url = "/" + page.self_and_ancestors.map { |p| p.slug }.join("/")
  page.save
  match page.url => "pages#show", :defaults => { :id => page.id }
end
```

Note that that will update each `page` every time your `routes.rb` is loaded and that might not be what you're looking for. You might want to put the URL setting elsewhere and just have this:

```
Page.all.each do |page|
  match page.url => 'pages#show', :defaults => { :id => page.id }
end
```

in your `routes.rb`.

The usual approach for this would be to have one route:

```
get '/:slug' => 'pages#show', :constraints => { :slug => %r([\p{Alnum}_.-/]+) }
```

And then use the `:slug` instead of the `:id` to find the page:

```
def show
  @page = Page.find_by_url(params[:slug])
  #...
end
```

Then you don't have to worry about dynamic routes at all, you just need to make sure the `url`s are right and that they're indexed. The precise form of the `:constraints` that you use would depend on what your `url` values look like. You'll also want to put this route at the bottom of your `routes.rb`.

Comment: So with that last option with get '/:slug'... slug can actually be a full trailing url like "page/anotherpage/anotherpage"? That's what I had wondered before but sort of assumed you couldn't do that in routes.

Also, it's weird that match doesn't do anything with :id.. but I can pass anything else in there and it will show up as a param. like what I ended up doing:
    match page.url, :controller => 'pages', :action => 'show', :page_id => page.id

Comment: @wejrowski: Yes, the `/:slug` route will let you pull in `:slug`s that contain slashes, you just have to adjust the `:constraints` to match what you're looking for and make sure it comes after your other routes. I checked the docs again it seems that you're right about `:id`, it should end up in `params` and I don't know why it is being treated differently; I fixed that part of my answer. I think the `/:slug` approach is really what you're after anyway.